how do I intergrate Django with fastapi
I'm trying to integrate FastAPI with Django ORM to perform async CRUD operations in my application. I want to take advantage of FastAPI's async capabilities while using Django's ORM for database operations.
I've followed the steps outlined in the FastAPI documentation and managed to create a FastAPI app. However, I'm having trouble integrating it with Django ORM for async CRUD operations.
Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction on how to integrate FastAPI with Django ORM for async CRUD operations?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What are you having troubles with? I'm not sure what your end goal by doing this is, but it'll usually be preferable to use django's own async mode instead. If you just want the orm part, you can see how you do async calls to it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/#queries-the-orm - so it comes down to what you're trying to do, what you've tried and what errors you're getting.

yes django supports async in djnago 3.1 and above versions , I have worked with that but hear this is  mechine test given by  a company so i have to impliment this through fastapi

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/?h=django%2C this doccumentation by fastapi

Take a look at Django Ninja.

Although Django Ninja is  very similar to fastapi and good alternative for this also but I alredy mention that  this assigment  given by a company so ...

I don't know exactly this would work for you or not, but you can generate your SqlAlchemy models with sqlacodegen from your existing Django ORM models and your database. so you generate your models and work with them in your FastAPI app, and perform your crud operations and queries on your database throw your FastAPI model.
